# Python Beginner -- How Can I Clean Up This Section Of Code

Tags: python, code-cleanup

This is part of the first python script that I've built from scratch. The complete code is designed to take a number of beads to use in a beadwork project and assess whether certain design patterns will work. The code is functional, and I've run it through pylint until my score is over 9.5, but I'm being told that the function "number_selection" has too many branches and I'm looking for help cleaning it up. I know there's got to be a simple way to make this code much less verbose and to get rid of all of my if statements, but I'm at a loss.

"beads", by the way, is a global variable supplied from raw_input

Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks for the help.

```
def number_suggestion():
''' if number entered does not work, then find the closest 
usable numbers, figure out which number provides the greatest 
number of design options and suggest that number. 
'''
next_lower = beads
next_higher = beads
list1 = []
list2 = []
add_one = 1    

# find next usable next_lower bead number
while next_lower >= 12 and next_lower % 6 != 0 and \
next_lower % 9 != 0 and next_lower % 12 != 0:
    next_lower -= 1
# find next usable next_higher bead number
while next_higher >= 12 and next_higher % 6 != 0 and \
next_higher % 9 != 0 and next_higher % 12 != 0:
    next_higher += 1

# add elements to list while counting to next usable number   
if next_lower >= 12 and next_lower % 6 == 0:
    list1.append(add_one)
if next_lower > 12 and next_lower % 9 == 0:
    list1.append(add_one)
if next_lower > 12  and next_lower % 12 == 0:
    list1.append(add_one)
if next_higher >= 12 and next_higher % 6 == 0:
    list2.append(add_one)
if next_higher > 12 and next_higher % 9 == 0:
    list2.append(add_one)
if next_higher > 12 and next_higher % 12 == 0:
    list2.append(add_one)

# make a suggestion, but not if the number works 
# in that case, return True
if beads >= 12 and beads % 6 == 0:
    return
if beads >= 12 and beads % 12 == 0:
    return
if beads >= 12 and beads % 9 == 0:
    return

# if number is less than 12, print error message 
if beads < 12:
    print('Please use 12 or more beads in your design.')
    return  

# if number doesn't work, suggest better options     
if len(list1) == len(list2):
    print('\nThere was an error.') 
    print('Try either ' + str(next_lower) + ' or ' \
    + str(next_higher) + ' beads')
elif len(list1) > len(list2):
    print('\nThere was an error.') 
    print('Try ' + str(next_lower) + ' beads instead.')
else:
    print('\nThere was an error.') 
    print('Try ' + str(next_higher) + ' beads instead.')
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic; it might belong on code-review.se

Comment: This is better suited for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: In addition to submitting it to codereview, please explain the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks -- I flagged the question and asked a moderator to move it (per google search). This is my first question, and I'm not sure if there's a better way to move the question than just reposting there and deleting here.

Comment: Also, the algorithm is intended to suggest two numbers, one below the number supplied by the user, and one above, that pass tests that would lead to the number being usable for creating designs in the beadwork. Basically, if the number is divisible by 6, a certain design pattern will work, if by 9, a different patter, and if by 12, yet another pattern. Other larger numbers would work, but the design elements that could be created would span such a large area of the beaded object that they would be unusable.

Answer (score 1):

I've gone over your code and changed it somewhat.

The reasons for the changes are in the code as comments.

```
# Test a number for being >= 12 and divisible by 6
test_div_06 = lambda num: num >= 12 and num %  6 == 0

# Test a number for being >= 12 and divisible by 9
test_div_09 = lambda num: num >= 12 and num %  9 == 0

# Test a number for being >= 12 and divisible by 12
test_div_12 = lambda num: num >= 12 and num % 12 == 0

# These are tests in a list
tests = [test_div_06, test_div_09, test_div_12]

# The original if statements were repeated everywhere.
# Now they are defined as functions only once.

def passes_test(test_count):
    # Return a list of the tests applied to a number
    return [test(test_count) for test in tests]

def passes_any(test_count):
    # Return True if any of the tests are True
    return any(passes_test(test_count))

def number_suggestion(bead_count):
    '''
    if number entered does not work, then find the closest 
    usable numbers, figure out which number provides the greatest 
    number of design options and suggest that number. 
    '''
    # Sanity checks should occur first.
    # Why calculate anything if you don't need to?
    # If number is less than 12, print error message 
    if bead_count < 12:
        print("Please use 12 or more beads in your design.")
        return  
    # Number is fine; no suggestion needed
    elif passes_any(bead_count):
        return

    # Find next usable next_lower bead number
    next_lower = bead_count
    while next_lower > 12 and not passes_any(next_lower):
        next_lower -= 1
    low_count = len(passes_test(next_lower))

    # Find next usable next_higher bead number
    next_higher = bead_count
    while next_higher > 12 and not passes_any(next_higher):
        next_higher += 1
    high_count = len(passes_test(next_higher))

    # If number doesn't work, suggest better options     
    # If common behaviour occurs independent of input state,
    # it should be expressed that way.
    # That's why this print statement was moved to here,
    # because the value of counts had no effect on its occurrence.
    print("\nThere was an error.") 
    if low_count == high_count:
        print("Try either %d or %d beads" % (next_lower, next_higher))
    else:
        # The elif and else have been merged into one.
        # The reason being its that their outcome is almost identical.
        # We can calculate the next_best suggestion using an
        # inline if else statement
        next_best = next_lower if low_count > high_count else next_higher
        print("Try %d beads instead." % next_best)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    beads = raw_input("Please specify number of beads: ")
    number_suggestion(int(beads))
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment and code suggestions. I've been trying to use list comprehensions like you did, but for some reason I wasn't seeing/understanding how to apply it here. Your comments have been very helpful and I appreciate the time you put into this. Thanks for helping me learn Python.

Comment: Also, can you explain if __name__. I've been running the code from the command line (although I'd like to convert it to a small app for personal use as my next project). Should I use the raw_input here for the entire code? I have it as my only global variable just after my doc string at the top.

Comment: The `__name__` variable is a global special variable which contains the name of the current module. If you run a python script, as in `python some_script.py`, the `__name__` variable becomes equal to `__main__`, which is to say the __main__ module. This allows the code to tell if it's been imported as module or being run as a script. The `beads` variable in this context is also a global variable; that if block it lies under is in global scope.

Comment: the line "test_div_12 = lambda num: num >= 12 and num % 12 == 0" is redundant.  You are already testing for num % 6

Comment: @Back2Basics, that's correct. It was written that way to show the equivalence with the tests in the original code, regardless of how redundant they were.